# If you complement a sum of money with an adjective, do you need to use an article?

Tags: grammar, articles

Suppose, here's a sentence,

> Federal spending on healthcare increased by 15%, albeit to (a) still relatively small 500 billion.

Do I need to use an article because of the adjective? I noticed that sometimes, a word that usually goes with no article or a different type of article is preceded with 'a'/'an' when it's modified, for example 'a buoyant dollar' (instead of 'the dollar'). Does some sort of nominalization take place in my example?

Comment: In that specific sentence, yes. But not if it's plural. Also, at least in some other sentences, you can replace *a* or *the* with *one* (or *this* or *that* or a possessive pronoun).

Comment: So the numeral becomes a noun, doesn't it?

Comment: I would say it's a [pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one) in *one still relatively small X*: "a certain indefinitely indicated person or thing // saw *one* of his friends."

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica What part of speech is '500 billion' in my example? Pronoun?

Comment: In *she ate one apple*, *one* would be an adjective of quantity, but, in this case, *500 billion* is a compound noun.